# why should i return reference when i compare three objects?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i tring to learn operator overloading and i dont get somthing.
when i do:

```
    class Point
    {
public:
    void show(){ cout << "the point is(" << _x << ", " << _y << ")" << endl;}
    void print(){ _x = 1; _y = 1; }
    void operator+=(const Point &other){
        _x = other._x + 100;
        _y = other._y + 100;
    }

private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};

int main()
{
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    p1 +=p2;
    p2.show();
    getchar();
}
```

its work. but when i change it to:

```
Point p1;
Point p1;
Point p2;
Point p3;
p1 +=p2 +=p3;
```

its doesnt and i need to return (*this). why is it? if someone can explain it to me i will be greatfull.. thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you need to return a reference here is that `p2 +=p3` does not evaluate to `p2` after `p3` has been added to it.  What it does evaluate to is the return value of `operater+=` of `Point` which is `void`.  You cannot add `void` to `p1` so you get the error.

Another way of looking at `p2 +=p3` is `p2.operator+=(p3)`.  Here we can clearly see we do not get `p2` but instead we get what `p2.operator+=(p3)` returns.

This is why we return a reference.  It allows us to chain the results together like you are trying to do.  If you do not return a reference then you have to break the chain.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
p1 +=p2;
```

You're actually calling

```
p1.operator+=(p2)
```

It returns `void` though it shouldn't (see [Assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)), but it's not the problem here since you're not using the return value anyway.

But when you do

```
p1 += p2 += p3;
```

It's actually

```
p1.operator+=(p2.operator+=(p3))
```

and now returning `void` is a problem since operator += expects a value as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator += has return type void.

```
void operator+=(const Point &other);
^^^^^
```

So a call of this operator may not be used in other call of the operator +=.

Otherwise it would look like

```
Point p;

p += void;
```

A valid definition of the operator could look like

```
Point & operator +=( const Point &other )
{
    _x += other._x;
    _y += other._y;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: _"Otherwise it would look like `p += void`"_ Not really, no